# C# ODBC using parameters in IN() query

Tags: c#, odbc, where-in

New to C#, trying to put an array into an IN() SQL statement.
In other words, perform a query something like:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN( [array_elem_1], [array_elem_2] ... )

Fairly easy to do in PHP/MySQL:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN("' . implode('","', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $values)) .'")');
```

But best I could figure with C#/ODBC:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN (" + String.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("?", values.Count)) + ")", conn))
{
    foreach (var kvp in values)
    {
        var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param.Value = kvp.Key;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Is there perhaps a nicer way to do this without so much code?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [SqlHelper](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=435)? I think it will be what you want

Comment: and, here is the [source code](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid5F6557C27DD01854BC85719A8B8A25A468393A08.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So basically, I have to use an external library - there's nothing in the ODBC interface to make things easier?  I was thinking more along the lines of an 'escape string' function somewhere...

Also the page seems to say it only works with SQL Server...